# How can I make a bot send a message, then the bot reacts to it then detects when some reacted to it?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

So I'm making this thing where you can do this command and it checks if you purchased a thing or not (it gets sent to staff). So I have that bit working but I'm stuck on how to do something like where the bot says, "Are you done with this?" and it reacts to that message with the ❎ and ✅. And when you press one of them, it does the code.

Or make it so it only reacts with the tick and detects when someone reacted to it.

Currently I have:

```
message.channel.send(new Discord.RichEmbed().setTitle("Rank-Up Application:").setDescription(`**If you wish to send an application to get Ranked-Up in the Discord & ROBLOX Group, this is the right place to do it! **`).setFooter("When you have done that, say done.").setColor("#ff4757")).then(() => {
        message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, { maxMatches: 1, time: 90000, errors: ['time']})
        .then(collected => {
          message.channel.send(":grey_exclamation: **Sending...**")
          client.channels.get(`622386044914106388`).send(new Discord.RichEmbed().setTitle("New Rank-Up!").addField(`**The user ${username} has sent in an application to get ranked. Please check the following links to see if you should rank him. Remember: True = Owns Class, False = Doesn't own Class.**`).addField(`Plus: ${plus}`).addField(`Advanced: ${advanced}`).setTimestamp().setFooter("When you have done that, say done.").setColor("#ff4757"))
```

So that last line of code is the bit it should say the message under. I'm quite stuck on this and don't even know what start code I should put.

Comment: How can you make a bot send a message and react to the user's response in discord.js or any bot?

Comment: Is it possible for the user to react with the tick or cross specifically and the bot can pick that up?

Comment: Unless you meant what I just said. (the main question asked if the bot can react to a new message and detect when a user reacts to it. Maybe leave the x reaction out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this is what you're looking for. I use it on tickets for people to close them. Works fine for me.

```js
message.channel.send(`Message that will have reactions on it.`).then(msg => {
    msg.react('❌');
    // Wait 300ms to make sure the tick emoji is made after the first reaction. Just incase the API is on the slow side.
    setTimeout(function(){msg.react('✅');},300);

    // Create a filter to collect, making sure it only checks for non bot users.
    // If you want to check for the message author use user.id == message.author.id
    const filterEmojis = (reaction, user) => {
        return ['❌', '✅'].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && user.bot == false;
    };
    // Await for a user to react as per our filter above.
    msg.awaitReactions(filterEmojis, {time: 60000}).then(collected => {
        const reaction = collected.first();
        // Check if the reaxtion is an X.
        if(reaction.emoji.name === '❌') {
            // Do something when this is reacted too.
        }
        // Check if the reaxtion is a tick.
        if(reaction.emoji.name === '✅') {
            // Do something when this is reacted too.
        }
    }).catch(() => {
        // Catch errors.
    });
}).catch(console.error);
```

Comment: Got the main answer now. But is there any way it can keep on checking? Because it checks after 60000ms